# Navigation css ul li:hover

Tags: css

Hello newbie question, I'll just wanted to hover the li.about on the ul.second.. Can someone help me on this one..

```
<ul id="nav" class="clear">
    <li id="home"><a href="index.html"></a></li>
    <li id="about"><a href="about.html"></a></li>
    <ul class="second">
        <li><a href="www.yahoo.com">1st Link</li>
        <li><a href="www.google.com">2nd Link</li>
        <li><a href="www.google.com">2nd Link</li>
    </ul>
    <li id="gallery"><a href="gallery.html"></a></li>
    <li id="before-after"><a href="before-after.html"></a></li>
    <li id="loft"><a href="loft-conversations.html"></a></li>
    <li id="case"><a href="case-studies.html"></a></li>
    <li id="testimonials"><a href="testimonials.html"></a></li>
    <li id="faqs"><a href="faqs.html"></a></li>
    <li id="contact"><a href="contact.html"></a></li>
</ul>
```

css codes

```
#navigation ul#nav li#about:hover ul.second
{
    background:#CCC;
    padding:1px;
    margin:1px; 
    height:200px; 
    color:black; 
    z-index:1000; 
    width:200px;
}
```

Comment: First: Click edit, highlight your code, and hit the `{}` button.

Comment: Can you please make sure you go back to your previous questions and accept the correct answer, or post the solution (if you've located it on your own). This boasts the community, and provides a resource to others with similar issues. Also, you'll receive more attention if you're known to accept correct answers. ;-)

Comment: That's invalid mark-up, a `ul` cannot be a direct descendant of another `ul`. Enclose the second `ul` in an `li` (the only valid child of either a `ul` or `ol` element).

Comment: Do you mean you want `ul.second` to appear when you hover over `li#about`, like a drop down menu? Can you explain what you want to happen when you hover over `li#about` a litle bit more?

Comment: Also, your anchors in the nested UL are not properly closed.

Answer (score 0):

If its a drop down menu you're trying to do, then make use of the `display: none;` and `display: block` css properties.